# monitor tcp buffer sizes on machine

Tags: java, profiling, buffer, tcp

I have to profile a TCP based client server Java app ,  and a part of it is to monitor the TCP send and recv buffers sizes ( in real-time , as messages flow across , like monitoring memory and threads using VisualVM for a running app ). what is the best way/tool for this ?

Comment: Aren't those buffers maintained by the OS, not by Java? This may help: http://serverfault.com/questions/247329/query-tcp-buffer-sizes-for-a-socket-on-linux

Comment: yes indeed , I am asking how do I monitor them ? mention of Java is incidental to the question - not a factor to consider for the answer.